# Encountered error "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid asa React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi new be in Ractjs here, i want to render a `carousel` in home page of my existing application,
my ***index.js*** file contains

```
import React from 'react'
import HeaderContainer from 'containers/HeaderContainer'
import Footer from 'components/Footer'
import Flashes from 'containers/Flashes'
import Carousel from 'components/Carousel' #i have added for carousel functionality
export default (props) => {
 return (
   <div>
    <HeaderContainer />
    <Flashes fixed={true}/>
    <main id="page">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </main>
       <Carousel /> #this is too i added
        <Footer />        
   </div>
 )
}
```

my carousel.js in component folder is like

```
'use strict';

  var React = require('react');

  var Carousel = require('nuka-carousel');

  const App1 = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Carousel.ControllerMixin],
 render() {
   return (
    <Carousel>
       <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1"/>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2"/>
     <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide3"/>
     <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide4"/>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide5"/>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide6"/>
    </Carousel>
    )
  }
});
module.exports = App1;
```

How ever when i use above code in newly created app it works, please help me,

i have also tried with ES6 and remove mixins but still error persist

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');

var Carousel = require('nuka-carousel');

class App1 extends React.Component {

 // mixins: [Carousel.ControllerMixin],
render() {
  return (
  <Carousel>
    <img 
src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1"/>
    <img 
src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2"/>
    <img 
src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide3"/>
    <img 
src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide4"/>
    <img 
src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide5"/>
    <img 
src="http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide6"/>
      </Carousel>
    )
  }
}
module.exports = App1;
```

Comment: why are you mixing es6 modules and commonjs ? Also you're exporting App1 from carousel.js but importing Carousel inside index.js

Comment: Try checking what is actually getting returned when you `require` the `nuka-carousel` module.

Comment: @WilomGfx please see my edit

Comment: @PedroCastilho How can i check what require library fetch? i mean debug..

Comment: `var Carousel = require('nuka-carousel');`

`console.log(Carousel);`